# how to handle dynamic url in laravel

Tags: laravel, url, dynamic

i have a page called "jobs" in my application where all the jobs will be shown.
And i have search job input field on same page 
where user search a job using input field it will redirect him to "jobs?keyword=abc"
And i also have a jobs filter section where user can filter a jobs by "location, contract_types".

i have created form by some javascript where user fills some fields that field only get submited by form.

i.e

```
if user searches a job by keyword then url will be like "jobs?keyword=abc".
if user filter jobs by location then url be like "jobs?location=abc".
if user filter jobs by contract types then url be like "jobs?contract_type=abc".
if user filter jobs by keyword and contract types then url be like "jobs?keyword=abc&contract_type=abc".
```

every time user submit a form url gets changing.

so my question is how to handle dynamic url on routes

currently i have this in my route
Route::get('jobs', 'todocontroller@jobs');

And my controller todocontroller.php

```
public function jobs()
    {
        //some code here
    }
```

thanks in advance any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve all parameters sent using `request()->all();`

this should go within your `jobs` function in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

That is what [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests) do

```
public function jobs(Request $request)
{
     $request->all(); // this is where all the query string, body or others param contains in it..
}
```

Example

```
if user searches a job by keyword then url will be like "jobs?keyword=abc".
```

then `request->keyword` return abc

```
if user filter jobs by keyword and contract types then url be like "jobs?keyword=abc&contract_type=abc".
```

then `request->keyword` return abc, `request-> contract_type` return abc

using path

```
/url/location/{param}
```

in controller

```
public function jobs(Request $request, $param)
{
     $request->all(); // this is where all the query string, body or others param contains in it..
     echo $param; //display param
}
```

Comment: but what if i have a friendly url's like for keyword search jobs?keyword=abc this url should be jobs/abc - for location search jobs?location=abc this url should also be jobs/abc AND for keyword search jobs?keyword=abc&contract_type=abc this url should be jobs/abc/abc   how do i modify my route for this types of url ???